# Avocado from seed - to prune or not to prune?

Tags: pruning, germination, avocado

I trid to get an avocado tree started from a seed a couple of years ago. The advice from [this website](https://www.californiaavocado.com/avocado101/your-own-avocado-tree) was to wait until it was around 6-7 inches tall, then cut it down to about three inches to encourage growth of other branches. I tried it, but I either did it wrong or it was bad advice, because that avocado struggled ever after and eventually died.

I've started over this year with four seeds, and two of them are at about this point (actually, they're around 7-8 inches tall) with some really nice-looking leaves growing out the top. I can post pictures if this will help answer the question, but should I prune them back? If so, what is the best method of doing so and how should I select the height at which to do so? I thought that I would just prune it back to the lowest level of big leaves, but all of the big leaves are clustered at the top.

Edit: I just saw [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/is-it-too-late-to-pinch-back-my-avocado-plant); perhaps this is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have three 1.5 year old trees and a few seedlings from this year. I pruned the older ones for the first time this year when i repotted them, they took it well. One even grew three kind if equal branches. I did experiments on the seedlings, i cut one when it was around 20cm tall and only small leaves (1cm) were present and one at around 4cm. Both also regrew branches, the smaller one even two. I asked a similar question back in march with no answers, but I will update that questiom and link it here when I am at home, maybe that gives you a clue. BR

EDIT: Link to my updated question: [Need advice for pruning indoor Avocado saplings](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/44121/need-advice-for-pruning-indoor-avocado-saplings/46645#46645)

Comment: @John Doe  I added a link.